# ArgumentError while parsing date string in Ruby

Tags: ruby, linux

I'm trying to determine the amount of days from the last .rpm that was installed using ruby, however when I try to format using the Date class, I'm getting that it's an invalid date (ArguementError) on line 5. I've tried methods of converting it to an integer as well but nothing seems to work. Any thoughts?

```
require 'date'
require 'time'

tset = `rpm -qa --last | head -1 | rev | cut -d ' ' -f4-6 | rev`
atime = Date.strptime(tset, '%Y-%m-%d')
today = Date.today
btime = Date.strptime(today, '%Y-%m-%d')
daterange = ("btime - atime")
puts daterange
```

Here is the output of my rpm command

```
[root@default-centos-67 dev]# rpm -qa --last | head -1 | rev | cut -d ' ' -f4-6 | rev

18 Nov 2016
```

Comment: Can you provide an example output from your `rpm…` call?

Comment: Yes, it has been added.

Comment: It's worth noting that leaning on commands like `head`, `rev`, and `cut` through the shell is pretty messy. Why not do that all in Ruby? Would help to expose what that's supposed to be doing.

Comment: Would you have an example of doing it with Ruby?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of your `rpm` command is "18 Nov 2016" and your `Date.strptime` command is looking for a date with a different format.

Change:

```
atime = Date.strptime(tset, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

to

```
atime = Date.strptime(tset, '%d %b %Y')
```

I almost always turn to [the documentation on strftime](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Time.html#method-i-strftime) to help me with flags for parsing `Date` and `DateTime` objects.

Answer (score 2):

Your call to `strptime` isn't using the correct format for the date string you are parsing.

The correct date string is: `%d %b %Y`

- `%d` is the two digit (zero padded) day of the month
- `%b` is the abbreviated month name
- `%Y` is the 4 digit year

Note that these are space-delimited, not hyphen delimited.

All together, here's how to parse the date from `tset`:

```
Date.strptime(tset, '%d %b %Y')
```